# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING - SSH Artisan / Composer

Tags: php, ssh, terminal, composer-php, laravel-artisan

moved my laravel site over to my live server but having issues. I believe I need to run

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

to fix my errors. However in terminal i see these errors:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/artisan on line 46

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/sites/b/beta.buildsanctuary.com/public_html/local/artisan on line 46
```

I thought these errors were because of using an old php version. In the SSH terminal php -v says 5.2. However in my hosts cpanel i have changed the version to 5.5, and a phpinfo() shows its running 5.5.

Any ideas what might be happening here?

Comment: You could be running different versions in the web SAPI and in the CLI (command line) SAPI. Do a `php -v` from the command line to see

Comment: In the command line (terminal) php -v returns 5.2. How can I make terminal run a newer version?